# Why I couldn't see alert when click?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $('.filter a').on('click', function(){

        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          cache: false,
          url: 'example.json',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data){

          alert(data);

          },
            error: function(response) {
              $("#accordion").css("display","none");
              alert("Error occured because of no data");
            }

          });
    });
});
```

Frustrated for a while that I couldn't get data to show up. I am puzzled why alert is not even showing up for testing. Is there anything that I might have overlooked or missed?

**In case: JSON**

```
[
  {
    "name": "A",
    "type": "judge"
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "type": "con"
  },
  {
    "name":"C",
    "type":"whatever"
  },
  {
    "name": "D",
    "type": "o"
  }

]
```

**Updated**

I am able to get error pop up in ajax error. But still cant get the data to be processed. Why? I saw the json on network list so it is loaded properly. Don't understand why alert(data) is not showing if json is loaded.

Comment: You've have not closed the success method with `}`

Comment: @mohamedrias - yes i already corrected with `}` but still cant see anything

Comment: Are you making the ajax request to the same domain or different domain?

Comment: First check your browser's console for errors.

Comment: Add an error callback, you will know what's the error else check browser console

Comment: @mohamedrias - have error in but still couldn't see error pop

Comment: @VahidND  - see error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input. I checked -- what puzzled me more is that it points to `</script>` when it is closing right

Comment: @joe you need to add either timeout handler and/or statusCode hander as I suggested

Comment: Please setup a jsfiddle or share more js code to see the error. It's more related to mismatch of parenthesis

Comment: Are an ajax url  and a page url in same domain?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide your complete js code (the whole code between <script> tags). After checking all braces to match.

Comment: @tutankhamun what do u mean by page url? im using swig which spilt all files in pieces to be together in certain page. so the code is in layout template while filter html is in page template. it shouldn't affect. because I did same thing for the navigation toggle which doesn't use ajax though.

Comment: @VahidND - got it matched already no error. still I can't see any alert pop up for success or error.

Comment: Are you sure the click event is raised and works properly.

Comment: @VahidND - yes I test by putting alert msg under filter.on('click'....)

Comment: You should now inspect the sent request and the corresponding response using the network tab of your browser's Developer tools.

Comment: @VahidND - omg it says invalid and failed to load response =.=. JSON is on aws server so cannot get data from there ? Last night I recalled I could get data even only one.

Comment: @joe So does that mean it's a CORS request? or The json file is not available?

Comment: @mohamedrias - it does not say but I checked again - json is working with response in network. i checked with jsonlint to make sure that json is validated. i also added in error, complete, etc - now it is working fine. weird.